# ¿Como se hizo la función random?

Tags: lenguaje-agnóstico

Soy un programador bastante novato, por lo cual dudas como esa me aparecen de la nada. Específicamente lo que me gustaría saber es la lógica detrás de la función `random` de `Python` en específico, pero la verdad que me conformo con la lógica que tenga en cualquier lenguaje.

La duda no es de como se usa, ya que eso no tiene mucha dificultad, mas bien, es el como funciona para que esa función pueda generar un valor aleatorio en mi `script` o programa.

Comment: La implementacion de la funcion depende. [Te recomiendo esta lectura](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/marsaglia-rng.html) de George Marsaglia. Y [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167253/implementation-of-rand) que trata el tema. En la pregunta de paso se dan unas implementaciones pequeñas

Comment: Me da pena que preguntas interesantes como esta acaben cerradas por lo que he votado para que se reabra.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sin entrar en mucho detalle, posiblemente te sea suficiente saber que `random()` no devuelve realmente números aleatorios, sino lo que se denomina *pseudoaleatorios*.

En realidad siguen una secuencia perfectamente predecible (dado un valor inicial o *semilla*, se genererará siempre la misma secuencia). Sólo son aleatorios en el sentido de que pasan ciertos test estadísticos que pasarían también los números aleatorios (equiprobablemente distribuidos, cierto valor medio, cierta dispersión, autocorrelación cercana a cero, ausencia de patrones evidentes, etc.)
No es fácil diseñar un algoritmo de estos que cumpla con los requisitos estadísticos necesarios para que la secuencia parezca aleatoria. Como dijo Donald Knuth, *"Los números aleatorios no deben generarse con un método elegido aleatoriamente"*.

Python usa un algoritmo llamado [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister). Es el mismo algoritmo usado por un gran número de herramientas y lenguajes para computación científica (R, Julia, Matlab, Maple, Excel) y otros lenguajes de propósito general como Ruby o PHP.

Otro algoritmo frecuentemente utilizado es el llamado [Generador Lineal Congruente](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) que es el usado por Java, C (en la biblioteca estándar glibc), y muchos lenguajes antiguos (Borland C, Turbo Pascal o Visual Basic).

No es posible generar números verdaderamente aleatorios mediante un algoritmo, ya que el algoritmo dará una secuencia de pasos determinista. Pero esto es suficiente para muchos casos prácticos, típicamente juegos o simulaciones. Por desgracia hay también aplicaciones que necesitan números aleatorios "de verdad" y no *pseudoaleatorios*, especialmente los algoritmos relacionados con la generación de claves criptográficas. Para tener números más aleatorios hace falta algún fenómeno físico externo al algoritmo. En linux el kernel va recogiendo eventos aleatorios del mundo exterior (tiempo entre pulsaciones de teclas, movimientos del ratón, variaciones de la temperatura, etc.) y con ellos va creando una fuente de entropía que puede usarse después para generar números mucho más próximos a algo verdaderamente aleatorio.

Python te permite acceder a esa fuente de aleatoriedad mantenida por el operativo mediante:

```
>>> os.urandom(4)
b'\xe5\x05cZ'
```

que como ves te devuelve una secuenca de bytes aleatorios de la longitud que le pidas. Puedes usar esa base para generar a partir de ella un número, por ejemplo entre 1 y 6 para emular un dado:

```
>>> ord(os.urandom(1)) % 6 + 1
1
```

**Nota:** `os.urandom()` también funciona en Windows, aunque desconozco si Windows hace lo mismo que Linux con respecto a la recopilación de entropía.

Desde el punto de vista de la física, las únicas fuentes de datos verdaderamente aleatorias que existen, son las derivados de la física cuántica. En este sentido algunos computadores van equipados con hardware específico que utiliza fenómenos cuánticos como fuente de aleatoriedad. Algunos de estos computadores proporcionan una API pública que puedes usar si necesitas datos verdaderamente aleatorios.

El módulo python [quantumrandom](https://pypi.org/project/quantumrandom/) por ejemplo te permite acceder a una de estas APIs para obtener números verdaderamente aleatorios.

```
>>> quantumrandom.randint(1, 6)
5
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta!